# Angular $rootscope.$on where to activate deregistration function

Tags: angularjs, rootscope, angularjs-rootscope

I have event listeners activated by:

```
var unregisterSubscription = $rootScope.$on(event, handler);
```

The event is activated in component and/or directive.
I want the listener to listen when the user uses the scope of the listener, otherwise not.

now my question is where i activate the unregisterSubscription method?

Comment: Could you please add more context in your question? because this thing can be done in multiple places like `app.run` or inside a controller of current component itself..

Comment: What context I can add more?

Comment: what do you mean by **`where to activate deregistration`**?

Comment: The right place to activate unregisterSubscription method

Comment: You can call the `unregisterSubscription` method anytime to unsubscribe, as long as the variable in scope. Another option is to unsubscribe in the handler function itself

Comment: I can't call the function in handler because its not found from there..

Answer (score 0):

You can create destroy event in controller.

```
$rootScope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    unregisterSubscription(); // Call unregisterSubscription method.
});
```

Comment: $rootScope never gets destroyed during the application runtime

Comment: @Ladmerc it could appear inside particular component controller's `$scope`.

Comment: You can inject $scope or $rootScope into the controller

Comment: Then your `destroy` event listener should be on the controller's `$scope`, not on `$rootScope`

Comment: I don't have $scope